# SQL code error (OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY)

Tags: mysql, sql-fetch

I'm trying to determine an average temperature over one day, for home assistant. I have linked sensors to home assistant, which send data to phpmyadmin. I can't send the sensors separately via home assistant, but they are all listed in the folder status. See below.

[sensors in folder states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlkLb.png)

By sending a sql code via home assistant, I can search values in the database. So now I'm trying to find the average of the last 100 measurements (+/- 1 day).  To achieve this, I have written the following sql code.

```
SELECT AVG(`state`) 
FROM states 
WHERE state_id > (select state_id 
                    FROM states 
                    WHERE entity_id='sensor.weatherstation_ground_temperature' 
                    AND state <> unknown 
                    ORDER BY state_id DESC 
                    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY)
```

If I type this into phpmyadmin, I get the following error:

> 1064 - There is an error in the syntax used for 'OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY) LIMIT 0, 25' in line 1.

My question is: what am I doing wrong, or is there a better way?

Comment: Frech first rows only is not mysql syntax. Use limit instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch first` does not exist in MySQL; you need `limit` instead.

```
SELECT AVG(s.`state`) 
FROM states s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT state_id 
    FROM states 
    WHERE entity_id='sensor.weatherstation_ground_temperature'  AND state <> 'unknown' 
    ORDER BY state_id DESC 
    LIMIT 100
) x ON x.state_id = s.state_id
```

Other issues with your query:

- subqueries that use `LIMIT` cannot be used with the `IN` operator: you can use a `JOIN` instead
- `state <> unknown` should be spelled `state <> 'unknown'` (this is a syntax error)

Side note: `OFFSET 0` is the default, so I can be ignored here.

Comment: Sorry sql is all pretty new to me. When I enter the code I still get an error:

#1054 - Unknown column 's.state' in field list

I thought this might be the folder it was stored in and the column (sensor_logging.state). What should I change in this code?

Comment: @Tibert: sorry there was a typo, I just fixed it, can you please give it another try?

Comment: The code works, but the output is NULL and the sensor does register numbers.

Comment: I'm sorry my mistake had spelled something in dutch. Thank you so much!! this took me literly forever.