# Error while using FETCH/OFFSET fucntion in SQL

Tags: mysql

I am currently learning SQL, I was trying to get the 2nd highest salary using the following code:

```
SELECT Name, Address, Salary
FROM Employees 
ORDER BY Salary DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

This is the error that I am receiving:
*Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY' at line 4*

I have read article online, but I still can't find what the error is.

Comment: This is sql-server code that youare attempting to use in MYSQL the 2 dialects are different. If you want to learn sql server there is a free version available

Answer (score 1):

You have to use LIMIT instead of FETCH NEXT rows as it is not MySQL syntax.
Also go through the following link where it is mentioned briefly
[SQL code error (OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58877189/sql-code-error-offset-0-rows-fetch-first-10-rows-only)

USE THE FOLLOWING QUERY INSTEAD OF ABOVE ONE TO GET SECOND HIGHEST VALUE

```
SELECT Name,Address,Salary from Employees GROUP BY Salary ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: Thanks. I read some articles regarding this and all of them did the exact thing. I was so confused on what I am doing wrong.